# Facing issues while loading data into Hive

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

We are loading data from SQL Server to Hive through Sqoop. We are encountering few issues as mentioned below

A. Can we create a table schema in Hive through Sqoop while combining multiple table from SQL Server with joins ?

I want to create schema corresponding to joined output from the query specified in Sqoop command  arguments

B. Hive incremental updates in lastmodified mode needs a timestamp column in SQL Server table. That column will be used by the Sqoop to compare values with supplied timestamp.

When I tried the `timestamp` data type in SQL Server, Sqoop failed to create Hive table with error

> Hive does not support the SQL type for column LastUpdated.

LastUpdated has timestamp data type in SQL Server. SQL Server timestamp is not aligned will the SQL 92 standard. Datetime data type is not working either. Hive string column is created for SQL Server Datetime column.

What are the other alternative available to support lastmodified mode of the Sqoop incremental feature ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you read the sqoop docs both your answers should become clear.

A. yes: chapter 7.2.3. Free-form Query Imports @ [sqoop docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html)

you can run queries inside of sqoop to do the inital ingest.

B. yes: you can merge data to do your updates, also see the docs @ 13.2. Syntax

In case you want to do extra, more complex stuff you should consider just ingesting the data, raw. Then applying logic to it inside of hadoop. After all, it's meant for processing data. Sqoop does not support UDF's so you might want to look at Pig, Spark, SparkSQL for this.

Comment: Sqoop incremental updates not working on MSSQLServer  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2421

Comment: Well then, Is it possible to create a temp table where the timestamps are formatted as a bigint or something?